# if case calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im having some trouble doing calculation part.

Example:-
I have 3 field name called Total,Num1,Num2. The calculation should be as below:-

```
 Case 1:-- If Num1>Num2;
            Total: Display 0.00 

 Case 2:-- If Num1<Num2;
           Total: Display Num1*(-1)
```

Can someone help me on this coding.

Comment: What if `Num1` equals `Num2`? Anyway, a standard if/else or if/else if/else is all you need, `if (Num1 > Num2) {...} else if (Num1 < Num2) {...}`. When you say you have "field name", are you talking about HTML input elements with those names as ID or NAME attributes, or are you talking about JS variables?

Comment: If Num1 equals Num2 its wil display Total: Display 0.00. Im more like to JavaScript code here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: no attempts, unclear description, very basic/common programming language items are involved.

Comment: Im not a IT based student actually. Im doing some simple app where i need this calculation part to be done.Tats y im seeking help.

Comment: And i actually tried where i did not get the result as i  want.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not clear, I assume you have 3 variables called Total, Num1 and Num2. If so, the code is very simple. just like in other languages.

```
if(Num1 < Num2) {
    total = Num1 * -1;
} else {
    total = 0.00;
}
```

Since you have mentioned that if Num1 > Num2 and if they are equal, the total should be 0.00, you need only one `if` and one `else` part. No `else if` is needed.